# Plot diagram has a cut in its labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

[image]

I have tried to use scalebox but it still happens so no matter how i scale it the labels of my plots have these cuts

here is my code for that:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=16cm, height=5cm,
            xmin=0, xmax=10.2,
            ymin=-1.3, ymax=1.3,
            axis lines = left]

        \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,red] {sin(deg(x))} node[right] {$\sin{(x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,green] {cos(deg(x))} node[right] {$\cos{(x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,blue,dashed] {sin(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\sin{(2x)}$};
            \addplot [domain=0:9.2,samples=700,black,dashed] {cos(deg(2*x))} node[right] {$\cos{(2x)}$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \caption{Funktionsplot von Sinus und Kosinus.}
    \label{fig:sin}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please, provide a compilable code of what your are trying to do in order for people to be able to help you. Moreover, if you are using the `axis` environment and your labels are defined inside nodes, there might be a chance that they are clipped because the right part is outside the scope of the axes.

Comment: In my `pgfplots` test bed I can't reproduce your problem.  Please extend your code snippet to an MWE.

Comment: Any news? is your image really 16cm wide?

Comment: I've tried to change the width but is still cut

Comment: Does not even make sense there is enough space

Comment: Da hell 17 width did the job  Solved